# Google Crawler Ajax/Php Page

Tags: ajax, single-page-application, google-crawlers

**What I have**

First of all, how I have I have my site set up is the user is brought to the main screen, there is a dropdown menu with links, when a link is clicked it sends an Integer value to a function that sends 2 AJAX calls, 1 that queries a database for a new title and returns it Json encoded, and 1 one that does the same but for associated data. This is then returned, a big div is cleared and a bunch of dom elements are created holding the new data.

**What I Need**

I have already rewritten my URLs using the #! hashbang. And on the client side when the hash changes it parses out the parameter and sends it via AJAX to the PHP code that executes as normal. The problem is I need to provide a snapshot of the HTML. 90% of examples I find online create the DOM with the PHP code and then just echo back the completed HTML. The code I use to create the HTML DOM is rather complicated so its done on the javascript side. So they recommend the use of a headless browser. But Im on a shared hosting service so I believe I cannot use a headless  browser, and if I can I have no idea how to use a php/java bridge to connect the java code to php, create a snapshot, and return it to google.

EDIT: Is it possible just to have .htaccess redirect any _escaped_fragment_ urls to the #! url?

Comment: can you add the code of your index site? shared hosting will indeed probs not allow a headless browser, or java.

Comment: Well the index page is well over 1000 lines long so I'm not sure which parts will be helpful. So im not sure if this counts as spam (if so let me know Ill remove) but my website it hypedup.net, you can view page source and see everything I do.

Comment: the related pieces are at the top/validateHash() where I deal with hashchanges,  the function changeLocation() makes the ajax call that gets the data, and the function createDiv() that takes the data and creates all the div elements.

Comment: OK, looked at it, but I can't really help you :(

Answer (score 0):

You could precompile all the possible pages with a headless browser (e.g. [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org)) and then serve those static HTML files to the search engine based on the  _escaped_fragment_ value. Of course only workable if the amount of options is reasonably limited.